# Defining an Array in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was doing this online tutorial and I could not understand why is it that when defining both the delivery address and delivery type, they are both capitalised. But when it is being called in the validation it is not? Thank you:)))

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart
  validates :delivery_address, :delivery_type, :payment_type, presence: true

  DELIVERY_TYPES = ["Courier(DPD)", "Personal collection", "InPost"]
  PAYMENT_TYPES  = ["Cash On Delivery", "Bank Transfer", "Dotpay"]

end
```

Comment: The constants DELIVERY_TYPES and PAYMENT_TYPES that are defined here are NOT used anywhere (according to code shown). And delivery_type is snake_cases as per rails conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As xeon131 said, DELIVERY_TYPES and PAYMENT_TYPES are `constants`. More precisely, they are Class Constants (that is, constants defined in the context of a class). By convention, these are indicated using `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` as stated in the [Ruby style guide - constants](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#screaming-snake-case).

Note that Classes and Modules are also constants and are written using `CamelCase` ([Ruby style guide - class and modules](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes)).

`:delivery_address`, `:delivery_type`, and `:payment_type` in the context of `validates` are symbols that (1) are passed to the `validates` method (defined in `active_model/validations.rb`) and that (2) correspond to attributes of the Order model. The [Ruby style guide - symbols, methods, and variables](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars) states that these are written using `snake_case`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, DELIVERY_TYPES and PAYMENT_TYPES are `constants` and `delivery_type`, `payment_type` are `attributes` of the model `Order`.

> A Ruby `constant` is like a variable, except that its value is
>   supposed to remain constant for the duration of the program

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html

On the other hand, attributes are properties of the object.

Comment: To be a bit more precise, `:delivery_address`, `:delivery_type`, and `:payment_type` in the context of `validates` are symbols that (1) are passed to the `validates` method and that (2) correspond to `attributes` of the `Order` model.

Comment: nice explanation, feel free to edit my answer with this information or add a new answer. I will up vote you